# Cron job doesn't run script python in the specific directory

Tags: bash, scripts, python, cron, git

I created a simple python script to `add`, `commit`, and `push` all files in some directory. I want to do this daily by a scheduled cron job. But unfortunately, the script doesn't run. Before this, I do some research on how to check activities in my Ubuntu, and I see my cron job has been executed. So I was confused why the script doesn't run.

This is my cron job:

```
16 16 * * * cd ~/Desktop/Journey\ to\ Go/ && python auto-push.py
```

This is my python script:

```
import os
os.system('git add .')
os.system('git commit -m "auto push"')
os.system('git push')
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the `~` as cron does not expand it to the path of your home directory like an interactive shell does. Please use full paths.

Comment: so who is the person that does not agree with this? the ~ is the problem...